# Windows Azure - migration questions

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

After global overview about Windows Azure platform i still have some questions in my mind i would like you to kindly answer. Hope it will be also usefull for some people besides me.

> 1. One of my application uses sql server db for text data and second db which is just simply images db (folder structure own db) where
>      images are stored and by using ftp my aplication can download/upload
>      there. The question is:     a) If i would go azure does "sql azure" is
>      place where can i place my sql server db? b) What about my folder
>      structure database - is there some place on azure storage i could put
>      my folders containing images and configure ftp to it? I heard about
>      BLOBS but can i ftp to it?
> 2. Is there possibility to place Windows forms application to Azure that it could work as remote application which specific users could
>      access instead of installing on every client machine?
> 3. Regarding Worker role - is there possibility to just simply move Windows service application to azure as worker role or there are some
>      things which has to be rebuilt to work in azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If i would go azure does "sql azure" is place where can i place my sql
>   server db.

You could definitely use SQL Azure to host your SQL database. Other alternative would be to use a SQL Server inside a Virtual Machine.

> What about my folder structure database - is there some place on azure
>   storage i could put my folders containing images and configure ftp to
>   it? I heard about BLOBS but can i ftp to it?

Blobs is definitely the place to store files and folders though they don't support FTP. However there are many storage explorers available (both free and paid), using which you can upload files and folders from your local computer into Azure Blob Storage. Another alternative would be Azure File Storage.

> Is there possibility to place Windows forms application to Azure that
>   it could work as remote application which specific users could access
>   instead of installing on every client machine?

Yes, it is possible. Please look into [`Azure Remote App`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/remoteapp/) Service.

> Regarding Worker role - is there possibility to just simply move
>   Windows service application to azure as worker role or there are some
>   things which has to be rebuilt to work in azure?

You can't deploy a Windows Service application as is into a Worker role. You have to tweak your code a bit. Other alternatives that you may want to look into is hosting your Windows Service in a Virtual Machine (to the best of my knowledge, it should be without any code changes) or converting your Windows Service into a `WebJob`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to everything that Gaurav mentions and as he alludes to, you can also investigate Azure Files. You can mount file shares from any onprem application. Since Azure Files supports the SMB protocol, you can use standard file system API to interact with it.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files.